# Is there any way to save and resend HTTP requests?

Tags: http, firefox, web-applications, httpwebrequest, firefox-addon

I have a really buggy web application at work. In order to avoid using its interface, I want something that will save the HTTP requests I send with it, and enable me to resend them whenever I want. Do you know of anything that does that? Maybe there is an add-on for Firefox (I searched, but didn't find one)?

I need to be able to do this on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iMacros for firefox

According to plugin description:
"Automate Firefox. Record and replay repetitious work. If you love the Firefox web browser, but are tired of repetitive tasks like visiting the same sites every days, filling out forms, and remembering passwords, then iMacros for Firefox is the solution you’ve been dreaming of!"

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863/

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to intercept HTTP requests and responses between the browser and the client.

Fiddler also supports handcrafting and sending HTTP requests using its Request Builder feature:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but Fiddler seems to be available only for Windows. Do you know of any Linux alternative for it?

Comment: @mstaniloiu - you should make your requirement for a Linux solution abundantly clear in your question.